# when "nwserver.exe" stops, it doesn't launch the second program in c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm trying to open the "A" Program and when it crashes then it does not stop "nwserver.exe", it doesn't launch the second program.

```
 public void ReLaunch()
        {
            Process DKU = new Process();
            DKU.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\E:\\Steam\\steamapps\\common\\Neverwinter Nights\\bin\\win32";
            DKU.Start();
            DKU.WaitForExit(10 * 60 * 1000);

            if (!DKU.HasExited)
            {
                DKU.Kill();
                Process process = new Process();
                process.StartInfo.FileName = "E:\\Steam\\steamapps\\common\\Neverwinter Nights\\bin\\win32\\nwnxlite-loader.exe";
                process.Start();
            }
```

also when I'm opening the EXE Program then it shows exception

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Le fichier spécifié est introuvable
à System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
à System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
à WindowsProgram.MainForm.MainForm_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
à System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
à System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
à System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
à System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
à System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
à System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
à System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
à System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
à System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
à System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
à System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
à System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Please help me to solve this problem thanks

Comment: You need an exception handler try/catch so the code continues after the exception.  The current code when an exception occur is exiting the method Relaunch().

Comment: It is a basic file-not-found error.  That path doesn't make much sense of course.

Answer (score 2):

Your first string with path starts with

**C:\E:\**Steam\

Which is two drives. The error says in the first line that it could not find the folder you specified.